# Swift UIPageViewController - for the requested spine location (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin)

Tags: ios, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, swift5, xcode12

Here I Created *UIPageViewController* by programmatically. **When I load more than one ViewController** to *UIPageViewController*. App crashed.

**Check my code below.**

```
class PageVC: UIPageViewController {
    
    let colors = [UIColor.green, UIColor.red, UIColor.blue, UIColor.black]

    var pages: [UIViewController] = []
    
    override var spineLocation: UIPageViewController.SpineLocation {
        return .min
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.isDoubleSided = true
        
        colors.forEach({
            let page = UIViewController()
            page.view.backgroundColor = $0
            pages.append(page)
        })
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        
        self.setViewControllers(pages, direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Getting Error like below.**

[image]

Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Try setting `pageViewController.isDoubleSided = true`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue from another prospective. I was trying to change spine location from `options` when initializing the `UIPageViewController`. Following Apple Documentation i tried to wrap up the preferred spine location into an `NSNumber` and set it as the value for the `spineLocation` key in the options dictionary but the application always crash. Not sure why...

Actually, the only way i know to change the spine location programmatically is by returning the chosen one in the delegate method `spineLocationFor orientation`. You have to create another ViewController and add the custom PageViewController as a child. I know it's not the exact answer to your question but hope it helps. By code, using a UIPageViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

private var pageController: UIPageViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupPageController()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    pageController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                        y: 0,
                                        width: self.view.frame.width,
                                        height: self.view.frame.height)
}

private func setupPageController() {
    self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    self.pageController?.dataSource = self
    self.pageController?.delegate = self
    self.addChild(self.pageController!)
    self.view.addSubview(self.pageController!.view)

    self.pageController?.setViewControllers([UIViewController()], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
    self.pageController?.didMove(toParent: self)
}
}
```

.

```
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationFor orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewController.SpineLocation {

    // handle orientation cases if needed
    // assuming you only support landscape:

    let initialVC = UIViewController()
    let initialVC2 = UIViewController()
    self.pageController?.setViewControllers([initialVC, initialVC2], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    pageController?.isDoubleSided = true
    return .mid
    }
}
```